# Prettyfaces execute css , images javascript links

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

I am using prettyfaces for long time and i am facing problem with url that is executed.

Problem is like this.

My link : /example-goal
My xhtml. /desktop/examples.xhtml

```
<url-mapping id="examplePage">
  <pattern value="/example-#{exampleBean.filters}"/>
  <view-id value="/desktop/examples.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

in PrettyFacesFilter

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException{
  final String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
  System.out.println("requestURI"+requestURI);
}
```

In console when i print requestURI outputs are like this

```
requestURI/example
requestURI/faces/com.ocpsoft.dynaView.jsf
requestURI/desktop/examples.xhtml
requestURI/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml
requestURI/javax.faces.resource/watermark/watermark.js.xhtml
requestURI/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml
requestURI/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml
requestURI/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml
requestURI/javax.faces.resource/watermark/watermark.css.xhtml
requestURI/desktop/css/font.css
requestURI/desktop/css/style.css
requestURI/desktop/js/bootstrap.min.js
requestURI/desktop/images/logo.svg
requestURI/desktop/js/scripts.js
requestURI/desktop/js/bootstrap.offcanvas.min.js
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/about-health.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/administrator-dark.svg
requestURI/desktop/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/home.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/alphabet-dark.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/stars.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/location.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/logo.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/phone.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/body.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/line.svg
requestURI/desktop/images/icons/buildings.svg
```

Somehow i manage this pages to not be executed with flag control like

```
if (!requestURI.contains(".")){
 // Enters just /example
}
```

This images, css ,javascript link should be executed in code below if i dont execute them in this part /example page is returning empty page

```
if (request.getAttribute(RewriteLifecycleContext.LIFECYCLE_CONTEXT_KEY) == null){
        HttpRewriteLifecycleContext context = new HttpRewriteContextImpl(inbound, outbound, listeners, resultHandlers, wrappers, providers);
        request.setAttribute(RewriteLifecycleContext.LIFECYCLE_CONTEXT_KEY, context);
      }

      for (RewriteLifecycleListener<Rewrite> listener : listeners){
        if (listener.handles(event))
          listener.beforeInboundLifecycle(event);
      }

      for (RequestCycleWrapper<ServletRequest, ServletResponse> wrapper : wrappers){
        if (wrapper.handles(event)){
          event.setRequest(wrapper.wrapRequest(event.getRequest(), event.getResponse(), servletContext));
          event.setResponse(wrapper.wrapResponse(event.getRequest(), event.getResponse(), servletContext));
        }
      }

        rewrite(event);
```

How can i stop this link to execute. I need just /example. ?

Comment: What do you mean with "executed"? PrettyFaces MUST process all requests to check if some rule applies or not.

Comment: @chkal sorry that i cant describe my problem well. User enters domain.com/example, in prettyfilter class css, imagines , javascript links are processed like different link. it should just process /example link but piece of code process all link that are found on xhtml file. style.css, jquery.js, My question is how to prevent this. Why all links in xhtml are processed on Prettyfilter class?

Comment: In you example only requests starting with "/example-" will be matched and processed. You have to be careful with you mappings. PrettyFaces matches the patterns against every HTTP request. So if you pattern will match a CSS file, it will also be processed.

Comment: I think that i am not explaining well, in my mapping file there is no any match, as you said it should just matche /example- page. Firstly it process /example- , then in xhtml file there is a link to js, css , images file. it matches them and it matched .xhtml.
<pattern value="/example-#{exampleBean.filters}"/>  <view-id value="/desktop/examples.xhtml"/> in this example it should just match /example- and process it not example- and example.xhtml together am i right? but in my project it maches both of them.

Comment: How do you know PrettyFaces matches theses requests?

Comment: As i showed in example, i am writing outputs and it shows all requests. in /example- doFilters runs for all links as shown in question.

Comment: As I said before PrettyFaces MUST process all the requests with the filter. However, that's shouldn't be any problem for your application because if the request doesn't match any mapping, the request is just forwarded to the application.